Android Library Maven Error: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration
I recently updated legacy project for a company I'm working for to higher Gradle and for some reason gradle cant find one of the libraries used there.
Getting this error while rebuilding project:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDev_devDebugAndroidTestDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:dev_devDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.florent37:singledateandtimepicker:2.2.4.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/florent37/singledateandtimepicker/2.2.4/singledateandtimepicker-2.2.4.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/florent37/singledateandtimepicker/2.2.4/singledateandtimepicker-2.2.4.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/florent37/singledateandtimepicker/2.2.4/singledateandtimepicker-2.2.4.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.florent37/singledateandtimepicker/2.2.4
It is still in mvnrepository but for some reason my Gradle cant find it anymore.
Any suggestions how to fix this?
